# How do I change the font color in my source window?

Tags: fonts, color

I am using Texshop 2.47 currently.  Versions beyond that are not recommended for my OS.

I'd like to change the font colors in my source window.  In particular I want something easier on the eyes since one spends such long hours with these files.  For instance, white text on a brown background or something.  The relevant settings seem to come up in the Preferences window, under the Source panel.  There is a button to change the background color which works, but...

There is a button to set the font, with which one can change the style and size of the font in the source window, but altering the color has no effect.  Strangely the default color it displays is magenta, despite that the text is actually black, with blue/green/red for certain syntax.

There is a section of that same menu labeled "Parens Targets & Highlight Color" with check boxes next to {}, [], (), and <>, with the first 3 checked by default.  To the right of that it displays a box to change the color where again the default color is that magenta.  Altering the color, and altering the checkboxes, both have no effect.

While I'm at it, there also seems to be no way to change the font color in the preview window, while again the background can be changed easily.

Lastly, another minor concern about default settings:

I have my windows set so that my preview window is larger than my source window, and the zoom level is increased, and whenever I open a document it's set to open that way.  But there seems to be no way to set the scrolling on the preview window so that it's centered horizontally.  That is not a big deal since it's so easy to fix, but it is something I must do every time and it would be good if that could be a default setting too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I don't know about current versions, but this used to be impossible. You can change the colours used for syntax highlighting, but not the colour of regular text. Not sure what you mean about the preview window. Usually, 'preview' refers to the compiled document (e.g. pdf) and the colours etc. depend on the content of the document rather than the settings of your editor. (Unless you have a PDF viewer set up to substitute colours or whatever e.g. for accessibility, but then it would make more sense to just use those colours for the document.)

Comment: Under TexShop>>Preferences, under the Preview tab, on the bottom right is an option to change the background color.  If you change this, the background changes color in the window that displays your typesetting (the "preview window"), but that color change is not reflected in how it saves the PDF.

Comment: Hmmm. Sounds annoying ;).

Comment: Well actually I don't want the color change reflected in the printed PDF... I just want to also be able to change the font color in the same way.  Though I'm sort of becoming okay with not being able to do that.  I find a brown background, with default text colors, is less headache-causing when spending far too many hours LaTeXing.

Comment: I can understand wanting to change the source colours. Just I want to see the output as it actually looks. I'd find it confusing if it did not reflect the content of the document. But if TeXShop still hard codes the main colour of text in the source, you will be out of luck unless you compile your own version. (Can't remember if that is even an option.) As I say, you could certainly change the highlighting colours for syntax when I used it, but not the main text colour.

Comment: Yeah, I'm more interested in changing the source colors.  I just got to thinking, maybe my eyes would feel better if I did the same thing on the output side.  Of course I could just change the font color to print it differently too but that's not what I want.  I'm feeling more and more like this isn't really a big deal.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/change-default-color-scheme-to-something-else-in-texshop/97701#97701. It seems that the source-colour-modification is fixed in version 3.11. If you are stuck with an older version, I think you will need to use a different editor to achieve what you want.

Comment: OK. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26702/texshop-foreground-color-cant-be-set-to-desired-default. Version 3.05, maybe, but still much more recent than 2.47.

Comment: Hey thanks @cfr, would you care to post that reference as an answer?  In the meantime I've become okay with the default font colors, so I think I'm going to stick with the editor/version I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97648/change-default-color-scheme-to-something-else-in-texshop/97701#97701), there is a bug in certain versions of TeXShop which prevents the font colour being modified in the source window. (The colours used to markup syntax may be modified, but not the base colour, as I understand it.)

According to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26702/texshop-foreground-color-cant-be-set-to-desired-default) the bug is fixed in version 3.05 and later.

So, if you cannot update to a more recent version of the editor, I am afraid that you likely must find another editor or put up with the default colour.