# LyX: Change display color of multiple boxes?

Tags: color, lyx, boxes

I have a big LyX document with many of these boxes with background color "olive":

[image]

On my old PC, these worked well. But I just got a new PC and for whatever reason, the text in these boxes is now often too dark (or too close to the olive color) for me to see clearly. (I am otherwise pretty happy with my new PC's display, brightness, colors, etc. and how it works with the rest of LyX.)

Is there any way for me to (fairly) quickly change the color of all of these "olive" boxes (in my big LyX document)? (I can manually change the color of each box, but this will take a long time.)

(I'm OK with what these boxes look like in the output PDF and don't want to change that. I only want to change how these boxes appear to me in LyX.)

(I wonder if perhaps for example there's some setting where I can set "olive" to appear as "white" to me in LyX?)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about editing properties of LyX.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Where is the rule on this site that prohibits such questions?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "If you have a question about ... Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc. ... then you're in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: I have to admit that the question feels off-topic but others also ask about Emacs, AUCTeX etc. and get answers while there is a separate SE [(Emacs)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/). And according to [the last point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) , Q falls in topics of TeX.SE. My opinion.

Comment: @user24096 Maybe I am missing something, but now your question is: I do not like the colour obtained on the new computer, but I will show you neither a bit of the code nor the version of LyX and let someone guess what happens. Hence it is not a question about LyX but about the properties of your local (unknown) installation.

Comment: My question is about whether it is possible to adjust a color displayed in LyX. Not about any "local (unknown) installation". It is similar to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224145/how-do-i-change-the-font-color-in-my-source-window and countless others here.

Comment: Have a look in LyX's customization manual (which can be found in Help->Customization) at appendix B.2. It seems you can not change the olive color. But you can change the background color of those insets to something else.

Comment: The number of down votes and close votes seem harsh to me. There are lots of questions about various editors on this site.

Comment: @UdiFogiel --- That appears to be a clear answer; would you consider posting it as such?

Comment: @IanThompson: LyX seems to be regarded here as stupid/impure/dirty and so accordingly, questions here about LyX are often subject to knee-jerk down and close votes (usually by those who've never used LyX because it's beneath them).

Comment: Actually, It seems i was wrong or misunderstood the manual. See my answer.

Comment: @user24096 --- Personally, I _hate_ LyX and all integrated development environments. Thats's not a reason for questions about them to be downvoted or closed, though! Each to their own.

Comment: @IanThompson: Yup exactly. If I think X is disgusting and have never tried it, I don't go around the internet downvoting, nitpicking on, and trying to censor questions about X (questions that I have no understanding of). I just move on with my life.

Comment: @user24096 Actually a lot of LaTeX users around here *have* tried LyX, and many  dislike it even more after trying it. They feel it restricts what they can do. They are used to having full control over the LaTeX produced, and since LyX is not a LaTeX editor (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28822/can-i-think-of-lyx-as-a-latex-ide), they cannot just edit the LaTeX as they want. It is really hard for them to understand why some people (like myself) choose to be subject to the restrictions imposed by LyX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will open LyX's application and go into `Help->About LyX->Version`, you should see a directory called `User Directory`.

There should be a file called preferences in that directory. Open that file with any text editor and in the color Section write `\set_color "olive" "<HTML COLOR>"`, where `<HTML COLOR>` is the html color code for the color you want, e.g., `#0000ff` for blue.

After you have finished editing the preferences file, save, return to LyX's App and go to `Tools->Reconfigure`. When to program finishes exit LyX and reopen it.